# Why getTheme doesn't work well on Application

Tags: android

I realize, for `Context.getTheme()`, it usually doesn't work well if we use `Application` as the `Context`

```
MyApplication.singletonInstance().getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.actionBarDeleteIcon, typedValue, true);
// typedValue.resourceId will be 0x0, which is invalid
```

However, if I use `Activity` as context, it works well

```
MyFragment.this.getActivity().getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.actionBarDeleteIcon, typedValue, true);
// typedValue.resourceId is valid
```

I was wondering why we cannot resolve attribute through `Application`?

In manifest, we specific theme information is found at `Application` level. So, I thought getting theme from `Application` object does make sense.

```
<application
    android:theme="..."
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because apparently the object returned by `getApplicationContext()` isn't a complete `Context` object, as noted [in this answer by CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7298955/1100355):

> It's not a complete `Context`, supporting everything that `Activity` does. Various things you will try to do with this `Context` will fail, mostly related to the GUI.

One potential solution is to manually set the theme on that `Context`, like this:

```
getApplicationContext().getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.MyTheme, true);
```

But this method is not endorsed by the Android dev team; the correct solution is to use `Activity` for things related to the UI, like `getTheme()`.